# Monitorar url de WebView

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

Olá! Estou fazendo alguns testes em minha aplicação android e em uma determinada activity pretendo colocar uma webview. Gostaria de monitorar o url dessa webview, para assim quando o usuário entrar em uma url predeterminada (exemplo: www.google.com) a aplicação realize determinada ação (exemplo: deixar botão de visível). Realizei algumas pesquisas relacionadas a isso porém não consegui esclarecer minhas dúvidas. Gostaria de saber como posso implementar tais características a minha aplicação.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar um [WebViewClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) para interceptar alguns eventos.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
      super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
      // Uma pagina comecou a ser carregada
    }

    @Override public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onPageFinished(view, url);
      // Uma pagina terminou de ser carregada
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
      super.onLoadResource(view, url);
      // Carregando um recurso
    }
});
```